# SHACL validation using other shapes

Tags: validation, owl, ontology, shacl

I have question related to SHACL validation. I want to validate a class based on the result of other validation. I currently have two shapes, one that indicates if an objective has no connections and another one that validates if the perpective is the Base Perspective. Objetives are related to perspectives using the "contributesToPerspective" property.

I want to create a conditional shape, similar to the first shape but with a diferent result if the objective is connected to the Base Perspective. Any ideas?

Current shapes:

```
`bso:ConnectedObjectives 
a sh:NodeShape ;
sh:targetClass bso:Strategic_Objective;
sh:message "Needs to be connected to other Strategic Objectives" ;
sh:or (
[sh:path bso:hasCauseEffectRelationship;
sh:minCount 1 ;]
[sh:path [sh:inversePath bso:hasCauseEffectRelationship];
sh:minCount 1 ;]).

bso:BasePerspective
a sh:NodeShape ;
sh:targetClass bso:Perspective;
sh:property [
sh:path [ sh:inversePath bso:isBaseFor ];
sh:minCount 1;
sh:severity sh:Info;
sh:message "This node is the Base Perspective";
sh:deactivated false;
].`
```